# Show that if $G$ is a finite cyclic group then $G^*$ is cyclic and $o(G)=o(G^*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $G^*$ be the group of all homomorphisms from a group $G$ to the set $\mathbb C^*$ i.e the group of all non-zero complex numbers.

Show that if $G$ is a finite cyclic group then $G^*$ is cyclic and $o(G)=o(G^*)$

**My try**:

Since the group $G$ is cyclic say $G=\langle a\rangle $ then every homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb C^*$ will depend on its value on $a$.How to construct a homomorphism $\phi$ such that $f=\phi^n$ for any $f\in G^*$??

Comment: Try $\phi(a) = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{\text{ord}(a)}}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have if $n=\operatorname{ord}(G)$

$$\forall f\in G^*, f(a^n)=f(a)^n=f(e)=1$$

So it boils down to studying the group of the nth roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Given $G=\langle a \rangle$ with $a^n=1,$  Define $f \in G^*$ by $f(a^k)= e^{2k\pi/n}$ (the $n$ roots of unity).  Now let $h \in G^*.$   We'll show that $h = f^k,$ for some $k.$   Observe that $h(a^n)=1,$ so that $h(a)$ is a root of $z^n=1.$  In particular, for some $k$ we have $h(a)=e^{2\pi k/n} = f(a^k) = f^k(a).$  Similarly, $h(a^j)=f^k(a^j)$ for each $j=1,2,\dots,n.$  We conclude that $h= f^k.$